# What are the post-DST timezones in the EU/EEA member states?

Tags: eu, timezones

In March 2019, [the EU Parliament voted to abolish DST](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20190321IPR32107/parliament-backs-proposal-to-end-switch-between-summer-and-winter-time-in-2021) in the EU and EEA, although different sources contradict each other when this takes effect.  From [the full text](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/TA-8-2019-0225_EN.pdf):

> Article 1
>
> 1. Member States shall not apply seasonal changes to their standard time or times.

What member states have declared they will stay in their current time zone ("permanent winter time"), and what member states have declared they will shift time zones ("permanent summer time")?  I am planning international travel this year and for scheduling cross-border travel, it is rather relevant to know what the time will be in different countries.  Even if it doesn't take effect this year yet, it would still be useful to know for next year.

Comment: NB: perhaps this question can only be answered next year...

Comment: I think your second link is not the actual adopted text. Your first link says the last year was postponed from 2019 to 2021.

Comment: I don't think any countries have officially announced what time zone they will be going with in the future.

Comment: [Here](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/TA-8-2019-0225_EN.pdf) is the text adopted by the EU Parliament. Also, I don't think this has actually progressed to the actual directive stage yet (though I'm not quite sure what is missing, probably approval by the EU Commission of the text which was substantially modified from the one they proposed).

Comment: @jcaron It needs to be approved by the Council, then published in the official journal of the EU.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed directive has not yet been fully adopted yet. The text proposed by the EU Commission was substantially modified by the EU Parliament in March 2019, so it's probably back to the EU Commission and the EU Council for more changes.

One of the main changes was the move of the last year for "seasonal time changes" as they call it from 2019 to 2021.

With a bit of time to go back and forth between the EU Commission, EU Council and EU Parliament, it'll probably take a few more months to be adopted.

Also, being a (proposed) directive and not a regulation, it needs to be transposed in national legislation, which will again take (at least) a few more months. And since a lot of people need to know such changes well in advance, the first "missing" change won't happen for months after each of the 27 member countries have adopted their relevant national legislation.

It's not impossible the last year of summer time won't happen until 2022 or later. I don't think we will have a clear picture of what countries pick summer or winter time for quite a while.

Answer (score 4):

While the [European Commission voted to abandon Daylight Savings Time](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/MEMO_18_5641), this  must be approved by Council of European Union and the European Parliament according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country). Therefore it is not a done deal. This might mean the exact terms and deadlines might be altered before final approval but in its current form, the change would happen in 2021 either in the spring or fall depending on which state stays in summer time and which one in winter time. These have [until April 2020](https://www.almanac.com/content/time-scrap-daylight-saving-28-countries-may-end-dst#) to decide, so it will be a few more months before this question can fully be answered.

Comment: Any update on this?